# Allow only leading and trailing spaces with Numbers

Tags: jquery

I need to have a `textbox` which accepts below:

1. Allow only Numeric with length of 6 digits
2. Range from 000001-999999
3. Allow only leading and trailing spaces (not between digits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can have space at start then 6 digit then can have space.
You should perform one more check like this.

- ^ should start with
- \s* 0 or more space
- [0-9]{6} 6 digits
- \s* 0 or more space
- $ should end with

```js
var re=/^\s?[0-9]{4,6}\s?$/;
function check(a){
  console.log(re.test(a) && a.length==6);
}
check('123456'); // true
check(" 1234 "); // true
check(" 12345"); // true
check("     "); // false
check(" 12345 "); //false
check("12345 "); // true
```

Comment: Max length is 6. If leading and trailing spaces are there then the digits would be 4.

Answer (score 0):

Is Jquery a requirement for creating this? You could use an input with restraints like so:

```html
<input type='number' max='999999' maxLength='6' min='1'>
```

I'm not entirely sure if the maxLength is needed, as its usually used for strings.

Comment: Yes JQuery is must

Comment: good approach but not work in old browsers which didn't support HTML5